# Why to use Foreign Key Constraints?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a PHP application which Db design was created by another guy who added FK constraints(*On Cascade delete etc*) between tables. So far what I am used to do is to put a FK in another table. For instance we have two tables:

**Users**

- ID
- Name
- CountryID

**Countries**

- ID
- Name

At application Level I will create two Separate INSERTs calls. If FK is present, then what change do I need to make at my application level?

Comment: Nothing ..... Just make sure when inserting a user that it's countryID value exists in the country table, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Guys why to downvote this question? Is it because I asked a *dumb* question?

Comment: @HaukurHaf means I gotta make all INSERTS anyway

Comment: yeah.  There is no such thing as cascading inserts.  If the user you are inserting has a countryid which is not present in the foreign key table, you'll need to insert a row into that table first with the correct ID, then insert the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the row you reference with the FK exists before you create the row in the other table.

… but you are probably doing this already as that is the logical order to create the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys enforce referential integrity.
These constraints guarantee that a row in a table order_details with a field *order_id* referencing an orders table will never have an *order_id* value that doesn't exist in the orders table.

Foreign keys aren't required to have a working relational database (in fact MySQL's default storage engine doesn't support FKs), but they are definitely essential to avoid broken relationships and orphan rows (ie. referential integrity). The ability to enforce referential integrity at the database level is required for the C in **ACID** to stand.